# LINQ: Sort records in ascending order with NULL values last

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, sorting

I want to sort the records in ascending order based on a column called DisplayOrder. If DisplayOrder is null or 0 then those records should come as last. By default DisplayOrder with 0 or null appear as top records.  I would like to ensure that all records with a NULL DisplayOrder appear after records with a non-NULL DisplayOrder and then sorted by the DisplayOrder which ensures that all records with a DisplayOrder are sorted correctly.

Here is how I was trying to do achieve it.

```
public DataResponse<EKGType> GetByPage(KendoGridPost kendo)
    {
        try
        {
            DataResponse<EKGType> response = new DataResponse<EKGType>(ResponseType.Failure);

            using (BusinessEntities context = new BusinessEntities())
            {


                IEnumerable<EKGTypes> items = context.EKGTypes
                                                     .ToList()
                                                     .Select(c => MapEntity(c))
                                                     .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder.HasValue)
                                                     .ToList();

                response.Data = items.Skip(kendo.Skip).Take(kendo.PageSize).ToList();
                response.Count = items.Count();
                response.ResponseType = ResponseType.Success;
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return HandleDataResponseException<EKGType>(ex);
        }
    }
```

This returns the records with null/0 values first. I been searching for past hour and could find answer to do it in sql but not in linq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `int.MaxValue` or something for those with `NULL`:

```
IEnumerable<EKGTypes> items = context.EKGTypes
                              .ToList()
                              .Select(c => MapEntity(c))
                              .OrderBy(c => 
                                  c.DisplayOrder.HasValue 
                                  ? (c.DisplayOrder == 0 ? (int.MaxValue - 1) : c.DisplayOrder) 
                                  : int.MaxValue)
                              .ToList();
```

So you effectively sort by `DisplayOrder` while the ones with `DisplayOrder == null` will be treated as if their `DisplayOrder` was `int.MaxValue` and the ones with `DisplayOrder == 0` as if their `DisplayOrder` was `int.MaxValue - 1`.
So at first all non-NULL and not-0 will be sorted by their `DisplayOrder`, followed by the ones with `0` and finally the `NULL` values.

Comment: After putting ?? int.MaxValue I get error saying 
"Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' "

Comment: did you remove the `.HasValue`? it's only `c.DisplayOrder ?? int.MaxValue` without `HasValue`

Comment: @RenéVogt That solution works for null values, but what about the requirement for 0 to come last as well?

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to take off .HasValue. Like you said it works for NULL values but I need values of 0 to be displayed at last as well

Answer (score 6):

The `OrderBy()` method allows you to pass in a custom comparer. Something like:

```
public class NullAndZeroLastComparer : IComparer<int?>
{
    public int Compare(int? x, int? y)
    {
        int xValue = x.HasValue && x != 0 ? x.Value : int.MaxValue;
        int yValue = y.HasValue && y != 0 ? y.Value : int.MaxValue;
        return xValue.CompareTo(yValue);
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
IEnumerable<EKGTypes> items = context.EKGTypes
    .ToList()
    .Select(c => MapEntity(c))
    .OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder, new NullAndZeroLastComparer())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Like that answer too, but I mostly prefer to put the logic directly into `OrderBy` than to create a whole new class for that. +1 anyway